# Getting Null Values on AJAX post in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I tried so many times to debug this code but it doesn't seem to work at all. I am using chosen jquery on my application.

**Here is my code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var status = [];
 var method = $(this).attr('data-method');

 var config = {
   '.chosen-select'           : {},
   '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
   '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
   '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
   '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
 }
 for (var selector in config) {
   $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
 }
     $("#test").chosen().change(function(e, params){

   console.clear()

   $("#test :selected").each(function(i,selected)
   {

          status[i] = $.trim($(selected).text());
   })

 console.log(status);    
 var new_var = JSON.stringify(status);

   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo site_url('request/result') ?>",
             data: { data: new_var }
         }).done(function(data) {
             alert( "Data Send:");
         }).fail(function() {
             alert( "Data Not Sent" );
         });
         e.preventDefault();

  });    });
```

The new_var holds the array values but i cant post its value to my controller.

**Controller**: request.php

```
  public function result(){
     echo json_encode($status);      
     die(); 
  }
```

I am debugging it on firefox on the network tab i can see values on params but on the response tab it returns **NULL** I cant seem to solve the problem for almost a week. I do not have any ideas how to solve it because i'm new to AJAX

Comment: what other thing you tried : like `echo json_encode($_POST['data']);`

Comment: Your question lacks detail which will help greatly. Your question needs to explicitly explain what your problem is and what you expecting the Ajax to return please. However, look at your result function in PHP. You are trying to access a variable that is not in the scope of the function, and so you are effectively passing the JSON_Encode no data. This will cause json_encode to return no data. This is likely your problem however without more information, it is hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to read from $_POST array:

```
  public function result(){
    // Your variable is here:
    var_dump($_POST['data']);
    // echo json_encode($_POST['data']);      
    die(); 
 }
```

Please remember to cleaning $_POST, e. g. using [filter_input](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_filter_input.asp)